# Why does executing a webhook via the discord API return a 404 error?

Tags: python, discord, webhooks

Whilst trying to execute a webhook, I've been getting 404 errors. The url I'm using is exactly what the Discord docs tell me to use: [https://discord.com/api/v10/webhooks/{webhook.id}/{webhook.token}](https://discord.com/api/v10/webhooks/%7Bwebhook.id%7D/%7Bwebhook.token%7D). However, I've been able to successfully create and delete webhooks. Finally, to test this error, I waited about a day after creation to see if it took some time for the url to work, but this also turned up a 404 error.

When creating a webhook, I use [this](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#create-webhook) method. Upon doing so, it returns json containing something like this:

```json
{
  "name": "test webhook",
  "type": 1,
  "channel_id": "199737254929760256",
  "token": "3d89bb7572e0fb30d8128367b3b1b44fecd1726de135cbe28a41f8b2f777c372ba2939e72279b94526ff5d1bd4358d65cf11",
  "avatar": null,
  "guild_id": "199737254929760256",
  "id": "223704706495545344",
  "application_id": null,
  "user": {
    "username": "test",
    "discriminator": "7479",
    "id": "190320984123768832",
    "avatar": "b004ec1740a63ca06ae2e14c5cee11f3",
    "public_flags": 131328
  }
}
```

I used [this](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook) bit of documentation to attempt to execute the webhook to send a message but to no avail. I use a url that uses the id and token in the json of the webhook, so with the JSON above, the url would look like this: https://discord.com/api/v10/webhooks/223704706495545344/3d89bb7572e0fb30d8128367b3b1b44fecd1726de135cbe28a41f8b2f777c372ba2939e72279b94526ff5d1bd4358d65cf11. I have checked to make sure that the program is using the right URL, and it is. What am I doing wrong to get the 404 error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the API correctly from what I can tell, it's likely something that goes wrong when executing the webhook.

You can verify this by sending a get `GET` request to your webhook URL (for example by opening it in your browser), and see what response you get.

For example, a successful call for this URL would look like this:
https://discord.com/api/v10/webhooks/730533481892106727/aPKOoEoamLq9pVnKHT3gF-whSrtrsnkWlOA3xPQPMNBsK5vhe9PC82-e7bu3BEFESQfaw

```json
{
  "type": 1,
  "id": "730533481892106727",
  "name": "Spidey Bot",
  "avatar": null,
  "channel_id": "501452852364050123",
  "guild_id": "413797995205889283",
  "application_id": null,
  "token": "aPKOoEoamLq9pVnKHT3gF-whSrtrsnkWlOA3xPQPMNBsK5vhe9PC82-e7bu3BEFESQfaw"
}
```

It seems like missing a forward-slash `/` will result in a 404, so that might be your issue.